# WCF how to use WS addressing standard namespace: “http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing”

Tags: wcf, wsdl, addressing

Calling the wsdl of my WCF web service, I read

```
xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex">
```

But I need to set

```
xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

tow liines below the namespace you need is defined as wsa10. what counts is which prefix is used inside the WSDL, is it wsa or wsa10. If it is wsa10 then you are ok. If not use a custom binding and set:

```
<textMessageEncoding messageVersion="SOAP11WSAddressing10" />
```

Comment: Thank You but I Have to use wsa instead of wsa10

Comment: Thank ypu but I have to use wsa instead of wsa10. My wsdl is xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" and I need to set it im xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing

Comment: in general it should not matter if the wsdl has wsa or wsa10. please explain in more details where things will not work with wsa10.

Comment: Part_1
They asked me to develop a web service for java client given me the wsdl file.
I developed the software using WSE 3.0, but they sent me an error
"the fault condition is caused by using a wrong namespace to wsa. We are using the “Web Services Addressing 1.0” specification (see http://www.w3.org/TR/ws-addr-core for details).
The validation of the data stream failed, because you use the namespace xmlns:wsa=”http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing”.
The correct Action header (based on “http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing”) was not found. This is a formal fault."

Comment: part_2
So I used the WCF

With WCF I get the WSA10 in the WSDL file set to "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", but they tell me that they can not use the web service because  I'm using a standard wrong and this can be seen questioning my wsdl

I tried in different ways but WSA is always ...
xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" 

<soap:Fault> 
      .. 
<faultstring>Technical validation error</faultstring> 
 ..    
<com:FaultBasic> 
<com:FaultReason>wsa:Action header is missing</com:FaultReason> 
</soap:Fault>

Comment: whether you use the rigtt or wrong standard is determined by the soap not the wsdl. they should be more specific: they should give you a sample of working soap request/response and you should compare it with the ones produced now. Most proably you need to correctly set the messageVersion property on the text encoding element.